# How to implement dynamic counter in Redis?

Tags: java, redis, redis-cluster

Recently, I need to query the cumulative times, amount, and days of transactions in a single week and within 7 days.

Here is an example to explain my demend. Suppose there is an user `u0001`, his transaction logs are as follows:

```
Time                    Amount
14:15:16 9-19 (Mon)     $21
20:05:45 9-20 (Tue)     $15
08:14:42 9-22 (Thu)     $9
17:34:24 9-23 (Fri)     $5
11:19:48 9-24 (Sat)     $6
13:15:14 9-24 (Sat)     $7
09:30:55 9-26 (Mon)     $3
10:34:45 9-27 (Tue)     $5
15:09:14 9-27 (Tue)     $10
19:43:25 9-28 (Wed)     $8
08:34:52 9-29 (Thu)     $2
10:09:28 9-29 (Thu)     $3
```

1. The cumulation in a single week refers to the summation from the start to the end of the week of the queried day. For instance, I query the cumulative times, amount, and days of transactions at 15:00:00 9-28 (Wed), the range should be 00:00:00 9-26 (Mon) to 23:59:59 10-02 (Sun). The valid transactions are

```
Time                    Amount
09:30:55 9-26 (Mon)     $3
10:34:45 9-27 (Tue)     $5
15:09:14 9-27 (Tue)     $10
```

Therefore, the results of `u0001` are

```
Total times     Total amount        Total days
3               $18                 2
```

2. The cumulation within 7 days refers to the summation of the past 7 * 24 hours from the queried time. For instance, I query at 15:00:00 9-28 (Wed), the range should be 15:00:00 9-21 (Wed) to 14:59:59 9-28 (Wed). The valid transactions are

```
Time                    Amount
08:14:42 9-22 (Thu)     $9
17:34:24 9-23 (Fri)     $5
11:19:48 9-24 (Sat)     $6
13:15:14 9-24 (Sat)     $7
09:30:55 9-26 (Mon)     $3
10:34:45 9-27 (Tue)     $5
15:09:14 9-27 (Tue)     $10
```

Therefore, the results of `u0001` are

```
Total times     Total amount        Total days
7               $45                 5
```

---

Now, I want to implement it by Redis. What are the suitable data structures and commands? How to implement the accumulation under the above two semantics?

Comment: How are your dates saved ? This format or via timestamps ? Do you need utc days or 24h chunks are fine ?

Comment: @JeanJacquesGourdin In my real system, the transaction time is timestamp in ms. utc days or 24h chunks can be accepted, albeit reluctantly.

Answer (score 0):

You can store timestamps as scores and amounts as members in a sorted set named after user ids.

Using your first example :

1. You can add entries in the sorted set with :

```
ZADD u0001 1664177699000 3
ZADD u0001 1664267699000 5
ZADD u0001 1664285699000 10
```

2. You can retrieve the number of times the user came via :

```
ZCOUNT u0001 now.timestamp-86400000 now.timestamp // 2
ZCOUNT u0001 now.timestamp-86400000*2 now.timestamp-86400000 // 1
//etc...
```

3. Get all members in the specified window

I dont think there is an easy way to add all of them in redis, they are strings, you could do a lua script for that. Like `ZRANGE...`and for each, `INCRBY nb:u0001 ARG` and then get the value

```
ZRANGE u0001 now.timestamp-86400000 now.timestamp // 10, 5
ZRANGE u0001 now.timestamp-86400000*2 now.timestamp-86400000 // 3
```

4. Remove members by chunks

```
ZREMRANGEBYSCORE u0001 now.timestamp-86400000*8 now.timestamp*7
```

You could also use redis time series, no idea how it works tho.